# Result from query in an if statement

Tags: php

I've been trying to make something in php where I could determine if somebody is blocked in my database and then echo seperate things depending on the result, I don't want to echo the result itself. I've signified being blocked by the value '1' and not being blocked by '0'. Sadly whatever I try to do I can't seem to figure out how it works. the only thing it echos is goodbye.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT blocked FROM Table WHERE name='$user'");
if ($result=="1") {
    echo "Hello";
}
else
{
    echo "Goodbye";
}
```

I hope somebody knows the answer.

Thanks in advance,

Kjeld

Comment: There are a bazillion tutorials for getting a value from a database query.

Comment: echo $result would probably help clear things up

Comment: `$result` is probably an array, so try changing the `if` statement to `if ($result[0] == "1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT blocked FROM Table WHERE name='$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['blocked']== 1) { 
    echo "Hello";
}
else
{
    echo "Goodbye";
}
```

Comment: Don't hope. Expect OP understand your correctly answer. =)